# Jsoup returns only the tags elements not the who HTML documents

Tags: android

### I want to retrieve the whole html document content using Jsoup but it retunrs only the tag. Am I making mistake.------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

`

```
package com.example.flashcardsdemo;` 
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

//import com.example.flashcards.MainActivity.Gethtml;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView text1;
    Document doc;
    Context context;
    Elements links;
    String s;
    //String UrlLink = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";
    String UrlLink = "http://postimg.org/gallery/5y7ulm9o/b2f8235e/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;
        Gethtml Ght = new Gethtml();
        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Ght.execute();
    }

    public class Gethtml extends AsyncTask {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading");
            dialog.setMessage("Html....");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(UrlLink);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                StatusLine line = response.getStatusLine();
                int statuscode = line.getStatusCode();
                if (statuscode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }

                doc = Jsoup.parse(UrlLink);
                String s= doc.toString();

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            text1.setText(doc.toString());
            Log.v("Document", doc.toString());
        }
    }   
}
```

Logcat Image;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux2Wf.png

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct url?? because I don't see nothing interesting on that url

Comment: FSM save us!!! did you read the documentation/references? `static Document Jsoup.parse(String ` **html** `) - Parse ` **HTML** `into a Document.`

Comment: I want to retrieve the image link from that url for testing purpose  have uploaded sample images to that URL.

Comment: No where I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using doc.html(). The following works for me:

```
String link = "http://postimg.org/gallery/5y7ulm9o/b2f8235e/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Edit: I just checked the implementation of toString(). In fact it is the same as html() in this case. Your problem is, that you used parse() with an URL, while you should have used it with the html string.

Comment: after adding doc.html(); I get the same tag as output not getting the whole document.

Comment: Which tag are you getting as output?